# Sort map by value property

Tags: clojure

I am currently trying to figure out a way to re-arrange entries within an existing map based, on a function apllied to its values, such as `count`:

`(def map1 '{A: (1 2 3) B: (1 2) C: (5) } )`

Sort by `(count (vals map1))`

=> `{C: (5) B: (1 2) A: (1 2 3)}`

Is there any straight-forward way to accomplish that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sort-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort-by) with anonymous function:

```
(def map1 '{:A (1 2 3) :B (1 2) :C (5)})
(sort-by (fn [e] (count (val e))) map1)
(sort-by #(count (val %)) map1)
```

or with [composition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp):

```
(sort-by (comp count val) map1) 
=> ([:C (5)] [:B (1 2)] [:A (1 2 3)])
```

Comment: I didn't know `sort-by` does also work on the values, not just the keys. Thank you!